# java thread safe code + an atomic method question

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have a class Manager that is going to be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, I want to know if I did it the right way ?
also I think I need RemoveFoo to be atomic, but I'm not sure

```
public class Manager
{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Foo> foos;
    //init in constructor

    public RemoveFoo(String name)
    {
        Foo foo = foos.Get(name);
        foo.RemoveAll();
        foos.Remove(name);
    }

    public AddFoo(Foo foo)
    {...}
}

public class Foo
{
    private Map<String,Bar> bars;
    //intialize it in constructor

    //same for RemoveBar
    public void AddBar(Bar bar)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            bars.put(bar.id, bar);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAll()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            //some before removall logic for each one
            bars.remove(bar.id, bar);
        }
    }

}

public class Bar
{}
```

Comment: i dont know about java but in c# youshould lock sync on some thing private so this is not the best pick...

Comment: Actually, it doesn't and making it so would slow the access to foos down.  You do need to check for null on foo though as @Aaron pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RemoveFoo` could be problematic. I suggest to use:

```
Foo foo = foos.remove (name);
if (foo != null) foo.removeAll();
```

instead. This makes sure that the map doesn't change between `get()` and `remove()`.

In `Foo`, it's enough to synchronize on `bars` instead of the whole instance. But that's just a minor optimization.

Comment: +1 That is much more concise, although the only thing that was really necessary was the check for null.  The remove will still work without error even if the item has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need synchronised methods as you are using a ConcurrentHashMap, however be aware that `Foo foo = foos.Get(name)` could return null as another thread could already have removed the entry from the map.

Members can be declared as `Map<String, Foo> foos`, but must be initialsed as `foos = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Foo>;`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `RemoveFoo(String)` as `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized void RemoveFoo(String name) {
    …
}
```

Also, be advised of the following:

- method names should be lower case, e.g. `removeFoo` instead of `RemoveFoo`. This is not C#. :)
- Every method needs a return type: `public removeFoo()` is not a valid method declaration, it needs to be `public void removeFoo()`.

Comment: :D yes, this is surely not C#

Comment: if I declare it as synchronized no other thread is going to be able to use this method at the same time ?

Comment: Right. A `synchronized` method can only be executed by one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a concurrentHashMap in Foo like

`private Map<String,Bar> bars = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Bar>();`

maybe you can do away with the synchronization in Foo as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are going to do on Foo and Bar, but it looks like a pattern  of deallocation.

If they are not referenced by others, just call foos.Remove(name); and let GC engine handle the deallocation.

Comment: I have some logic (go to DB) to do per each Bar before it gets removed from the Map